# Send email a specific pages of an Access report via Outlook

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a database and I would like some VBA code to enable me to email specific pages of an Access report via Outlook.

For example, if I want to attach page 10 to 20 from a report.

I know how to attach a report to an email. This is my code that working properly, but I want to send specific page from Access Report.

Thanks in advance.

```
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olItem As Variant
Dim rec As Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim fileName As String, todayDate As String

Set db = CurrentDb
todayDate = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")
fileName = Application.CurrentProject.path & "\Invoice_" & todayDate & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "rptInvoice", acFormatPDF, fileName, False

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set olItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
olItem.display
olItem.To = Nz(rec![EmailPrimaryContact])
olItem.Subject = ""
olItem.Attachments.Add fileName
olItem.htmlBody = "Dear & " < br > " "
olItem.display

Set olItem = Nothing
Set rec = Nothing
```

Comment: What is significant about pages 10-20? Access can filter reports by some `WHERE` clause logic but not by arbitrary pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Adobe as a printer option, consider [`DoCmd.PrintOut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.printout) after adjusting the report's [`Printer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.report.printer) property:

Use below subroutine to find Adobe printer

```
Sub Printers()
    Dim prtDefault As Printer

    For Each prtDefault In Application.Printers
        Debug.Print prtDefault.DeviceName
    Next prtDefault

    Set prtDefault = Nothing
End Sub
```

Adjusted VBA *(replaces `DoCmd.OutputTo...`)*

```
Sub OutlookEmailModule()

    ...

    DoCmd.OpenReport "rptInvoice", acViewReport                        ' OPEN REPORT
    Reports("rptInvoice").Printer = Application.Printers("Adobe PDF")  ' ADJUST PRINTER
    DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 7, 10                                      ' SUBSET PAGES
    ' PROMPTS YOU TO SAVE DOCUMENT AS fileName 
    DoCmd.Close acReport, acSaveNo                                     ' CLOSE W/O SAVING

    ...

    olItem.Attachments.Add fileName                                    ' USE SAME FILE AS ABOVE

    ...

End Sub
```

Comment: Beat me to it as I was composing similar answer. MS PrintToPDF or XPSDocumentWriter drivers might be possible alternatives.

Comment: Thank you Parfait. This will help